# How prove $\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m+1}{k}\cdot 2^k\cdot B_{k}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

we know  Bernoulli number such  identity
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+1}{k}B_{k}=0$$
see:[Bernoulli number  identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number)

> show that
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m+1}{k}\cdot 2^k\cdot B_{k}=0$$

where $B_{n}$ is Bernoulli number.

My idea:since 
$$B_{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}B_{1}+\binom{n+1}{2}B_{2}+\cdots+\binom{n+1}{n}B_{n}=0$$
and 
$$\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m+1}{k}\cdot 2^k\cdot B_{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\dfrac{(2m+1)!}{k!(2m+1-k)!}\cdot 2^k\cdot B_{k}=0$$

then I can't Continue.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $(B_n)_n$ has a generating function:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^
\infty \frac{B_n}{n!}x^n=\frac{x}{e^x-1}~\buildrel{\rm def}\over{=}~G(x)
$$
see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html). Hence,
$$
e^xG(2x)=\frac{x}{2\sinh x}
$$
and this is an even function. So, the coefficient  of $x^{2m+1}$ in the power series expansion of $e^xG(2x)$ is $0$.
That is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}\binom{2m+1}{k}2^kB_k=0
$$
Finally, it is well-known that $B_{2m+1}=0$ for $m\geq 1$, hence
$$
\forall\,m\geq 1,\qquad\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m+1}{k}2^kB_k=0
$$
Of course the result is not correct when $m=0$.